# Storing Combinatorial Values in a MySQL database - Bit masking, foreign keys, junction tables, or what?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, combinatorics

I'm creating a MySQL database with tables that contain information about different types of products.

As an example, let's say Table1 contains bicycles and Table2 contains t-shirts.

I want to be able to store information about things like which colors each of the items in each table are.

For example, there might be a bicycle in Table1 that's blue and yellow, and a t-shirt in Table2 that's red, green, and orange.

Originally I had intended to store color information as binary numbers in each table and use bit masking to figure out the colors of a particular object (i.e. 1 = red, 2 = blue, 4 = green, 8 = orange - if the value is 5, the object is Red and Green). I was going to have a foreign key table with the values for all the single colors (i.e. Red = 1, Green = 4) and use sums of the values from that table as bit masks.

I assumed doing it this way would be "faster", but I've been "Googling" this subject for weeks before making a decision and found out that it's "faster" to have a foreign key table so indexes can be used. (i.e., if you wanted to see if a t-shirt with the color value set to 13 included the colors Red and Green, rather than doing "13 & 5" , you would check row 13 in the foreign key table to see if the values for Red and Green were set to 1.)

The thing is, the list of colors I'm using is currently at 26, and I'm anticipating that it will grow. (I was trying not to go over 31 colors so I could use an INT column to store the values, where 0 = "none".) If I were to make a foreign key table to cover all possible combinations of 31 colors, it would have to have 2,147,483,647 rows and 32 columns (one true/false column for each possible color). Every time another color was added, I would have to double the number of rows in the table (like, one additional color would require 2147483648 more rows).

I assume it would be preferable to make a "junction table" like this:

```
+----------+------------+
| shirt_id |  color_id  |
+----------+------------+
|        1 | 1 (Red)    |
|        1 | 4 (Green)  |
|        1 | 8 (Orange) |
|        2 | 2 (Blue)   |
|        2 | 4 (Green)  |
+----------+------------+
```

Then there wouldn't need to be a gigantic table listing every possible combination (the vast majority of which might never be used). The thing is, there would have to be junction table for every product type, and there are going to be a large number of product types, meaning a large number of junction tables.

I'm using colors as an example, but I had actually planned to do this for several other "stackable" values as well (for example, a single object could be composed of hardwood and aluminum and glass and particle board and ABS plastic and PVC and cardboard...and so on, all at the same time).

My question is, **what is the most efficient method of handling situations like this?** Is there a method I haven't thought of that's preferred over these?

I'm only using colors as an example - the database will actually have a number of "stackable" attributes like this (things like material, fiber type, texture, finish, etc.) that can apply to more than one product type, and the "products" themselves will be "generic" and have have a "stackable" value that indicates the types of components that make them up (like, a "product" that includes a bicycle and a t-shirt packaged together).

Having written this, I imagine using multiple junction tables would be the most efficient way to do it. But as an "old-school programmer", it's difficult for me to get my head around the idea that making [for example] 30 different junction tables just for product component/color combinations alone could possibly be "preferable" to just directly analyzing bits in a binary value. (I do realize MySQL is not a Nintendo Entertaiment System...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've once implemented bit-masking on a field for different domains. However this was clearly a case that was going to provide a big performance improvement as it would avoid having to join 8~10 tables. Bit-masking is extremely fast, especially if the field is indexed. 
With the index for a 32-bit field then it will at maximum do 31 comparisons to find the resulting rows. 
 
Without the index it would still have to perform the bit-compare on every row.

However there is a big 'if'. It's not easy to maintain and the shirt colors will always be limited to the bit-length and in the case that you describe I would really opt for the junction table and just make sure to have the index on your foreign keys.

Comment: Thanks Genkus. I thought I read indexing doesn't help when using binary values and bit masking? And I didn't see anything saying it was "fast" - mostly the opposite. (People imply the databse will practically grind to a halt.) Also, I simplified my example, but on top of color there will things like material, fiber type, finish, etc. and many will apply to multiple product types. With junction tables, there'd need to be a LOT of them, and many queries would need more than 10 joins. From your description, it sounds like you used bit masking for reasons similar to mine.

Comment: BTW, I forgot to ask - what about the case I described in my question would lead you to opt for junction tables over bit masking? I probably shouldn't have simplified my example so much, but from what I've read it sounded like there were ~no~ instances where bit masking was "okay", so I didn't think it mattered how complex the example was...

Comment: The example given was indeed somewhat simplified and for such a limited use case it would have been too complex.
I might have jumped to some conclusions given my rather limited DB index knowledge and the performance gain was mainly measured in our application which uses Oracle as the DB instead of MySQL.
I've done some further reading leading to [bitmap indices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitmap_index). It seems that MySql doesn't support this index type yet and it is still a [requested feature](https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=1524).

Comment: If you really want then it is still possible to achieve this with [Fastbit UDF](https://github.com/greenlion/FastBit_UDF)

Answer (score 1):

The question of performance depends on the *queries* being used, as well as the structure of the data.  Your question doesn't include information on the queries.

But, there seems little reason not to use a junction table.  This would involve a table called `Colors` with an auto-incremented primary `ColorId`.  Then for each table that required colors, you would have a table, such as `BikeColors` with one row per bike and color.

I wouldn't attempt to do this using bit-fiddling, unless you have a really good reason to.  That is, unless you have tried a junction table, and for some reason that doesn't meet your needs.  A junction table can take advantage of indexes.  Bit fiddling generally does not.

Also, I would question why you have separate tables for bikes and T-shirts, unless you have a lot of columns that differ between them.  For most retailing purposes, one table would be sufficient for multiple products.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. The database is more complex than I described. Bikes and t-shirts have many values that don't repeat (t-shirts don't have brakes, bikes don't have sleeves). There's a main "SKU" table and SKUs can include more than one product type (like a bike and a t-shirt together)- another place I was going to use binary values. If I use junction tables there will be hundreds of them. Queries will all be read-only - data is permanent and any changes would be made by me. (It's informational, not for retail.)

My gut really says to use binary values, but so many places say it's a bad idea.